# JNI and static interface

Tags: java, c++, android, java-native-interface

Is JNI's "method signature" different if method is defined to return (static) interface ?

In my Java class I have this method:

```
public SharedPreferences.Editor getSharedPrefsEditor() {
    return mActivity.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
}
```

SharedPreferences.Editor is a static interface in SharedPreferences.

In my C++ JNI code I do this:

```
// 'env' is the java environment that JNI passes to us
// 'jObject' is the one that JNI passes to us (along with env)
jclass javaCallerClass = env->GetObjectClass(jObject);
jmethodID methodId_getSharedPrefsEditor = env->GetMethodID(
    javaCallerClass,
    "getSharedPrefsEditor",
    "()Landroid/content/SharedPreferences/Editor;");
```

For some odd reason, this doesn't work.  It compiles, but at runtime I get this:

> DEBUG/dalvikvm(19020): GetMethodID:
>   method not found:
>   Lcom/mangotaster/madballs/MyRenderer;.getSharedPrefsEditor:()Landroid/content/SharedPreferences/Editor;

I'm calling other methods in that class in pretty much the same way without any problems.

The only change seems to be the return value.
I did try to call the edit() function straight from JNI code, but got the same error - which makes me believe that my function signature "()Landroid/content/SharedPreferences/Editor;" is indeed wrong.

More info on the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nested/Inner classes don't use the standard namespace nomenclature in JNI signatures.  The inner class is actually translated to a normal class at the same level as the outer class by the Java compiler with the name "Outer$Inner".  I think you want `"()Landroid/content/SharedPreferences$Editor;"`.

Comment: How right you are @Tim!
Funny enough, this did cross my mind earlier but I dismissed it in my mind without trying it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

No need to guess about this, or ask on forums ;-) javap -s will tell you the correct JNI signature string for any Java method.

Comment: Excellent point! In this case:

javap -classpath /path/to/android.jar -s android.content.SharedPreferences

Gives you:

public abstract android.content.SharedPreferences$Editor edit();

  Signature: ()Landroid/content/SharedPreferences$Editor;